# NWaves Xamarin Android not play wav file

Tags: android, xamarin

```
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(fistBank, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var waveFile = new WaveFile(stream);
                signal = waveFile[Channels.Left];
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
```

Added to the project, added permissions for reading files, I get the path to the file. I press the button and silence ... The file does not play ... It does not even generate signals from examples

Comment: Perhaps open an issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/ar1st0crat/NWaves

Answer (score 0):

I check the wiki of NWaves. Playing and recording work only on Windows, since they use winmm.dll and MCI commands. You could use `MediaPlayer` in Xamarin.Android instead.

```
 string fileName = "WAV_1MG.wav";
            var player = new MediaPlayer();
            var fd = Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName);
            player.Prepared += (s, e) =>
            {
                player.Start();
            };
            player.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
            player.Prepare();
```

`WAV_1MG.wav` file is in the Android `Assets` folder with the `AndroidAsset` Build Action.